# how to get the location with the CLLocationManager every 10 secondes?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I want to get the different locations of the users in order to display him the trips he did. But in order to save my user's battery, I want to get his location just every 10 seconds with my `CLLocation` manager.

I first thought about not implementing the 10 seconds interval and get the user's location every time he move with the `didUpdateLocations` of the `CLLocationManager`, but when I simulate a drive I get new location every second and I think this is really bad for the battery, am I right ?

Answer (score 3):

Do not try to second guess the location manager. Your job is to set its properties appropriately, such as `distanceFilter`, `desiredAccuracy` and `activityType`. Apple will use every trick in the book to keep battery usage reasonable *given your settings*. As the docs tell you:

> Core Location manages power aggressively by turning off hardware when it is not needed. For example, setting the desired accuracy for location events to one kilometer gives the location manager the flexibility to turn off GPS hardware and rely solely on the WiFi or cell radios, which can lead to significant power savings.

If the goal is track location in the background, there are special modes for that, which save even more.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comments matt! Yeah my goal is to track location in the foreground but also when the application will be in the background. I also want to know when i don't get locations anymore in order to stop the current traject, i tried it with locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates but my program never enter to this fonction

Answer (score 0):

Check location every 10 second a lot frequent, it will be drain user's battery too fast.
If you would save battery, you should learn apple guide about location manager.
You need use `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy`

[Base guide CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager)

[Energy Efficiency Guide for iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH24-SW1)

[Location Awareness Programming Guide - Tips for Conserving Battery Power](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)

**Update**
Also you can check how fast user moving [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation) have [speed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423798-speed) and adjust [activityType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620567-activitytype)

Comment: I put a distance filter to 100 meter, but concerning the the desiredAccuracy, i need to retrace the traject of my user, so do you think i need the best accuracy for that ?

Comment: Best accuracy will drain the battery so fast that it is advisable only if the phone is plugged into a charger.

Comment: Ok i choose accuracyTenMeters, thanks. So now i have a distanceFilter to 100 with a TenMetersAccuracy. Do you think it's correct concerning the battery  ? ( notice that i have a switch buttons that allows the user to stop the localisation)

Comment: @SofianeBensliman it depends on you case. But it better than check location every 10 sec.

Comment: @SofianeBensliman Also you can check how fast user moving and adjust activityType. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620567-activitytype

Comment: "Do you think it's correct concerning the battery" Don't think. Test! Xcode provides extensive tools for finding out exactly what kind of energy usage is involved here. Please watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/417/ and _lots_ of other WWDC videos on this topic.